# Adding a variable in Django templates static tag {% %} enclosure

Tags: python, html, django, templates, variables

I have a project in Django Python.
And, I am trying to figure out how to add a variable in a {% %} enclosure

I'ved got variables set in this way:

```
CP_ENV_SMALLAPPNAME_CAPITALIZE <-- meta title variable
CP_ENV_FAVICON_PATH <-- favicon variable path


<title>{{ CP_ENV_SMALLAPPNAME_CAPITALIZE }}</title> <-- this works
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{% static 'img/{{CP_ENV_FAVICON_PATH}}/favicon-16x16.png' %}"> <--- this doesnt work
```

How can I insert CP_ENV_FAVICON_PATH into {% static %} enclosure in django ?

Comment: Did you tried like this ``{% static 'img/CP_ENV_FAVICON_PATH/favicon-16x16.png' %}``

Comment: you probably need to write a custom template filter/tags to pass that variable into a string on template side

Comment: @LinhNguyen I did what you said. Not ideal but that worked.

Comment: it's because the django built in static template tag is a method that accept a single string argument(path to the static folder in this accept). So whatever you pass in to static tag will always be converted to a string(that why you can't use other tag within static tag). I hope that explained it

Answer (score 2):

Hope this could help

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{% static "img/ "%}{{CP_ENV_FAVICON_PATH}}/favicon-16x16.png">
```

Comment: the second `static` call is unnecessary and would append STATIC_URL one more time

Comment: @IvanStarostin Yes your are right, I had edited it

Comment: This won't work with whitenoise or any complex static file handling